# Adodb: Postgresql select from two tables but return one set of results

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, adodb

I am new to SQL, and have two tables that hold data(I am using Adodb).  They both have keys that connect them together, so I wanted to select a name from the first table if that has a parent id in the second table.  I am using:

```
$db->GetCol("SELECT x_ast.name FROM x_ast, x_ast_tree WHERE x_ast_tree.parent='$parent_id'");
```

This returns an array with the correct data, but it is in there twice. (I assume because I asked it to come from two tables):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Trash
    [1] => Users
    [2] => admin
    [3] => Trash
    [4] => Users
    [5] => admin
)
```

How can I select a field from one table based on the data in another table, but only return one set of results?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't set a criterion for joining the two tables, so it's doing a cross join.

```
SELECT x_ast.name
FROM x_ast
INNER JOIN x_ast_tree
  ON x_ast.somefield=x_ast_tree.somefield
WHERE x_ast_tree.parent='$parent_id'
```

Comment: Beautiful, that worked!  I knew about join, just did not understand them yet.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Joins Between Tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html)